Route [daftar_mahasiswa] not defined in Laravel
I am working on a Laravel project and encountered an issue where I can't navigate to the "daftar mahasiswa" page. Instead, I get redirected back, and I see the following error message:
[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException(code: 0): Route [daftar_mahasiswa] not defined. at C:\\TA\\DITZ_TA\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator.php:512)
[stacktrace]

routes/web.php:
<?php
    
});


route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user']], function () {
    
    Route::get('/mahasiswa/daftar', [MahasiswaController::class, 'index'])->name('daftar_mahasiswa');
    Route::get('/mahasiswa/tambah', [MahasiswaController::class, 'create'])->name('tambah_mahasiswa');
    Route::post('/simpan-mahasiswa', [MahasiswaController::class, 'store'])->name('simpan_mahasiswa');
    Route::get('/mahasiswa/edit/{id?}', [MahasiswaController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit_mahasiswa');
    Route::put('/mahasiswa/update/{id}', [MahasiswaController::class, 'update'])->name('update_mahasiswa');
    Route::delete('/mahasiswa/hapus/{id?}', [MahasiswaController::class, 'destroy'])->name('hapus_mahasiswa');
    Route::put('/mahasiswa/{id}/update-ipk', [MahasiswaController::class, 'updateNilai'])->name('update_ipk');


In my view, I'm trying to create a link to the route using:
<a href="{{ route('daftar_mahasiswa') }}">Daftar Mahasiswa</a>
when php artisan route:list it listed
GET|HEAD  mahasiswa/daftar ........................................................................ daftar-mahasiswa › MahasiswaController@index  
 


Wild guess Try Route::group instead of route::group. Run php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache & php artisan cache:clear

thanks for answer but it still doesnt' work

in php artisan tinker, what's the return value for route('daftar_mahasiswa')?

= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mahasiswa/daftar"

when i goes in to route daftar_mahasiswa it return back to login panel (auth=user)

Isn't it strange that in the code it's called daftar_mahasiswa, and in the blade template it's also daftar_mahasiswa, but when you run artisan route:list, the route name is daftar-mahasiswa instead of daftar_mahasiswa?

@DITZ when i goes in to route daftar_mahasiswa it return back to login panel (auth=user) It's expected because you have added the auth middleware.

Can you explain what I should do because I'm still new to using Laravel

@DITZ I am not sure what is the reason but just for the test try to change the name of that route and check if it's working.

i change the route name before but it still not work

Don't forget to give as many debugging details as possible in the question, it helps other people pinpoint the problem.
